# Android, Error: Duplicate resources does not include info

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I got two compile errors;

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Error:Error: Duplicate resources
>
> Error:Error: Duplicate resources
>
> Information:BUILD FAILED in 5s
>
> Information:2 errors
>
> Information:0 warnings
>
> Information:See complete output in console

But these does not tell me which resources are duplicate. Settings->Editor->Inspections->Android->Lint->Correctness->Duplicate definitions of resources is on.

Can anyone help me to find out which resources are duplicate?

Comment: Is this full error log?

Comment: Error:Error: Duplicate resources
Error:Error: Duplicate resources
Information:BUILD FAILED in 47s
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Please update your question with full log.

Comment: Other parts of the log are just results, I updated.

Comment: Additionally, I added a library and some example code which contains some resources to my project, and trying to compile, there were more duplicate resources and many errors, I resolved them one by one, but I stuck here.

Comment: Check your layout files. There must be more than one time same xmls:// declarations.

Comment: There are just too many, it would take hours, I am checking now but there should be a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an Android Studio bug.

I fixed it by this way, reverted project to before I import the resources which causes trouble, then imported those again folder by folder, trying to rebuild each. But this time compile logs show which resources are duplicated.

I hope this kind of ide bugs to be fixed soon.